# Existence of 45 Degree angle between 3 Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Is it possible in n dimensions that 3 vectors have a 45-degree angle with each other?

```
<(x,y)= <(x,z) = <(z,y) = 45
```

is there also any condition for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible whenever $n \geq 3$.  It's pretty clear that this isn't possible for $n = 1,2$.

Let $\langle x,y \rangle$ denote the "dot-product" of the vectors $x$ and $y$.  Then the angle between $x$ and $y$ is $45^\circ$ if and only if $\langle x,y \rangle/(\|x\| \cdot \|y\|) = \cos(45^\circ) = 1/\sqrt{2}$.  If we choose unit vectors $x$ and $y$, then this becomes $\langle x,y \rangle = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

More generally, the angle between vectors is $\cos^{-1}[\langle x,y \rangle/(\|x\| \cdot \|y\|)]$.

In $n$-dimensional space with $n \geq 3$, we can always take
$$
x = (\cos(22.5^\circ),\sin(22.5^\circ),0,0,\dots,0)\\
y = (\cos(22.5^\circ),-\sin(22.5^\circ),0,0,\dots,0)\\
z = (1,0,\alpha,0,\dots,0)
$$
Where $\alpha$ is chosen so that $\langle x,z \rangle/\|z\| = 1/\sqrt{2}$, which is to say that
$$
\alpha = \sqrt{2\cos^2(22.5^\circ) - 1} = \sqrt{\cos(45^\circ)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}
$$

---

Another viable strategy to find the three vectors: begin with an equilateral triangle in $2$-space, i.e.
$$
(1,0),(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2),(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)
$$
Then, take
$$
x = (1,0,\alpha)\\
y = (-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2,\alpha)\\
z = (-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2,\alpha)
$$
Where $\alpha$ is chosen so that
$$
\frac{\langle x,y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies\\
\frac{-1/2 + \alpha^2}{1 + \alpha^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies\\
-1/\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\alpha^2 = 1 + \alpha^2 \implies\\
(\sqrt{2} - 1)\alpha^2 = \frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} \implies\\
\alpha^2 = \frac{1 + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2} - 1)} = \frac{4 + 3\sqrt{2}}{2} \implies\\
\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{4 + 3\sqrt{2}}{2}}
$$

Comment: (+1) More for the geometric intuition in the second part: the three angles are always equal by symmetry. When $\alpha=0$ the angles are $2 \pi / 3$, when $\alpha \to \infty$ the angles tend to $0$. By continuity, there will exist an $\alpha$ that corresponds to any angle between $0$ and $2 \pi / 3\,$, including in particular $\pi /4$.

Answer (score 2):

Three dimensions suffices.

\begin{align}
x &= (1,0,0)
\\
y &=
%(\cos(\pi/4), \sin(\pi/4), 0) =
(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}, 0)
\\
z &= (1/\sqrt{2}, 1-1/\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1})
\end{align}

These are unit vectors satisfying $\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x,z \rangle = \langle y,z \rangle = \cos 45^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I will show how to create such a vector for $n=3$. Start with vector $\vec{x}=(1,0,0)$. A vector at $45$ degrees is $\vec{y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1,1,0)$. The reason I choose the $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ factor is to have $|\vec x|=|\vec y|=1$. Now assume that $\vec z$ has a component out of the plane of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. We can write $\vec z=(a,b,1)$. You can use the dot product of vectors to calculate angles. $$\cos\theta=\frac{\vec u\cdot \vec v}{|\vec u||\vec v|}$$ You can now calculate $a$ and $b$. $\vec z \cdot \vec x=(a,b,1)\cdot(1,0,0)=a$. Similarly $\vec z \cdot \vec y=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(a,b,1)\cdot(1,1,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(a+b)$